# Favorite tags filter only shows a limited set of my tags

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

Whenever I go to my filters on stackexchange.com/filters, the automatically generated "Favorite Tags" filter only includes tags from two of my Stack Exchange sites and not all of them.  However, when I look at my account info, it properly lists all of my connected Stack Exchange accounts, so why does the favorite tags not include all of them?

Is there any way to update it?

Comment: You can [manually sync the tags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kG0lQ.png), but this doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well, @Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of a bug, an out-of-date version of your favorite tags were being loaded, even after clicking "re-sync".

It's fixed now, so all of your favorite tags appear in the [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/26848) now.